# How set follow-fork-mode as child in debugger using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb, clion

I have Linux system, and I writing program use **Clion IDE** which using **CMake**. I have a part my in program where I would like to **debug child process** 
I read a few topic from this forum, but I still doesn't know how or where just I can turn on this function:

[gdb debugging child process after fork (follow-fork-mode child configured)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126925/gdb-debugging-child-process-after-fork-follow-fork-mode-child-configured)

[How do I debug the child process after fork() in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199270/how-do-i-debug-the-child-process-after-fork-in-gdb)

I just have tryed to setup flag `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`  as `set follow-fork-mode child` but CMake give me error. 
Below screenshot with all flags which are uses to compile and dbug my program. 
So what and where I must set this function.

[image]

**..::EDIT::..**

I believe that is good way. I think Your tip was useful, but I have some next problem. After using Your instructions my code is crash on line

```
pid_t newProcessForClient = fork();
```

Statement is:

> (gdb) set follow-fork-mode child [New process 31667] warning: File
>   "/lib32/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your
>   `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load". warning:
>   Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread
>   debugging will not be available. [Switching to process 31667]
>   Continuing with signal SIGABRT.
>
> Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted. The program no longer
>   exists.

Comment: `set follow-fork-mode child` is a *GDB command*, not a compilation flag. Just type this command in gdb command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debugging settings have nothing to do with cmake. CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG states the debug flags for the compiler. However, you need to tell *set follow-fork-mode child* to the debugger. To do this, you need the following steps:

1. Set a break point at the beginning of your program (ie. the parent program, not the child program)
2. Start the program in the debugger.
3. Go to the debugger console (tab with the label *gdb*) in clion and enter *set follow-fork-mode child* and *set auto-load safe-path /*
4. Continue debugging

The command *set auto-load safe-path /* is supposed to switch of the auto-load restrictions according to the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto_002dloading-safe-path.html) of gdb.

Comment: Your post is useful. Realy IDE try switch to new proces but something is wrong. Could You look on **EDIT** in my post ?

Comment: I updated my post, however, this time it is not based on experience but on using google.

Comment: Ok I understand. I tryed set this option but is still this same. I think that, main question is solved, because Your tip is correct,. Now I must see what is wrong with my system. Thx

Comment: With CLion 2017.3.3 it is not working. I set `set follow-fork-mode child` from the gdb console but when the process being debugged forks a new process CLion debugger just disconnects.